# javascript global variable and return value

Tags: javascript

I wrote following code, but it is not returning tDate value, receiving undefined error.
console.log shows result, I think I using global variable wrong way.
seems like after the loop, tDate still not initiated,(inside the loop it is receiving value) how do I define global variable?

```
function getDates(){
    var tDate;
    var pool = new ConnectionPool(poolConfig, config);

    pool.requestConnection(function (err, connection) {
        if(!err) {
            var sql = "SELECT MAX(Date) from datatable";
            var request = new Request(sql, function(err, rowCount) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }

                // Release the connection back to the pool.
                connection.close();
            });

            request.on('row', function(columns) {
                columns.forEach(function(column) {
                    if (column.value === null) {
                        console.log('NULL');
                    } else {
                        var date = column.value;
                        var sDate = new Date(date);
                        sDate = sDate.toISOString().slice(0,10);
                        tDate = 'Today= ' + sDate;
                        console.log(tDate);
                    }
                });
            });

            connection.on('connect', function(err) {
                connection.execSql(request);
            });
        }
    });
    return tDate;
}
```

Comment: Did SQL injections cross your mind?

Comment: Johan what do you mean? This code is running on server,any advice?

Comment: What is *date*? Given `var sDate = new Date(date)`, likely it's a string, in which case `new Date(date)` is strongly advised against. Parsing of strings with the Date constructor is extremely unreliable, particularly if you are using an ISO string with no timezone (as `sDate.toISOString().slice(0,10)` indicates). Currently [*EMCA-262 ed 5*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) requires such strings to be local, the [*ed 6 draft*](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-date-time-string-format) requires UTC.

Comment: Well, it wouldn't be hard for someone to copy your script and replace `SELECT MAX(Date) from datatable` with `DROP TABLE datatable`, `SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables` etc.

Comment: hmmm seems like I have a lot of problems :( thank you guys for the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making the classic mistake of the code you've written will be executed in the same order as you see it. It won't. You're binding event listeners, that'll call callback functions if something happens. Only then (in the `request.on('row'` callback) will the value of `tDate` be modified.

Requests are, for the most part ASYNCHRONOUS operations, think of it like this:

```
function testCallback()
{
    var someVar = 213;
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        someVar = 'New value';
    }, 10000);//10 seconds
    return someVar;
}
console.log(testCallback());
```

This will **not** take 10 seconds to log, instead it'll log 213 almost immediately, but 10 seconds later, the (now inaccessible) variable `someVar` will be reassigned.

You can test this by doing:

```
function testCallback()
{
    var valObj = {someVal: 213};
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        valObj.someVal = 'new value';
    }, 10000);
    return valObj;
}
var o = testCallback();
console.log(o.someVal);//213, still
// wait 10 seconds
console.log(o.someVal);//new value <--
```

Comment: +1, also I would check if `column.value` actually _is_ a valid date value (a string that can be converted to a date). But to get it to work at all, I think your answer is right.

Comment: @davidkonrad—strings should not be passed to the Date constructor at all. Their format should be known, they should be parsed manually.

Comment: I am new to JS, I am c, c# programmer. Thanks for advice I will try to fix this.

Comment: @zevsuld: There's one thing you should keep in mind at all times when writing JS: in its heart, it's a functional programming language. Treat it accordingly. Think in functions, not in statements. If you do that, you'll be fine